# iSeries/AS400 level check error hangs ODBC call

Tags: c#, .net, odbc, ibm-midrange

I'm using a C# .NET ODBC connection to retrieve data from an iSeries (AS/400) database. If the files and procedures are not promoted properly on the iSeries side, the ODBC call will cause a *level check* error. Unfortunately, the handshake between the ODBC driver and the iSeries appears to be flawed, and the ODBC call simply hangs.

Changing the connection and command time-out values on the .NET side does not affect the call, which appears to hang forever.

Is there a way to force a time-out in this situation?

Or is there a way to forcibly terminate the ODBC call (i.e., from another thread that waits for a fixed time) and throw an exception?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what your problem is and it sounds like it could be a bug in the ODBC driver. However, ODBC does define asynchronous behavior via the statement attribute SQL_ATTR_ASYNC_ENABLE and there is an API SQLCancel to cancel an operations.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm using normal synchronous access through C#/.NET to the iSeries database. I'd like to kill the executing command when it hangs and exceeds some fixed time limit.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "kill". If you asynchronous mode and your driver supports it you should be able cancel (SQLCancel) the statement and continue ok. If you can't/won't use asynchronous mode and you want to continue using the connection after you've actually killed a stuck thread I think you're stuffed because it will probably break the network protocol.